# Swift equivalent of forcing a build failure based on certain macro definitions

Tags: swift

In Objective-C, you can trigger a build error based on macros. For example, say I have this macro defined:

```
#define DEBUG_ALL_LOGS
```

Then in my logging framework:

```
-(void)logMessage:(NSString *)message severity:(int)severity
{
  #ifdef DEBUG_ALL_LOGS
  NSLog(@"Log message level %i: '%@'", severity, message);
  #endif

  //Now pass the log message off to a file or whatever
}
```

To prevent this from making it into a production build, I can have something like this:

```
#if defined(DEBUG) && defined(DEBUG_ALL_LOGS)
#error Forcing all logs is only allowed in debug builds
#endif
```

(side note: this exact setup might not do what you expect because of `DEBUG` vs `NDEBUG`, but this is pseudocode-ish)

Now I can turn debug behavior on and off without worrying (much) about it making it into a production build.

How can I accomplish this in Swift? Swift doesn't have macros, and [uses global constants instead](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_macros_in_swift). But I don't think I can cause a compile error based on the value of a variable.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to have the condition in `logMessage` defined as `DEBUG && DEBUG_ALL_LOGS`?

Comment: @Sulthan yes, probably, but the implementation details of `logMessage` aren't particularly relevant. I'm more interested in how to fail the build.

Comment: @Sulthan or, more generally, how to set up a similar scenario - something that can only happen if it's a non-production build *and* a certain flag is somehow set - in Swift

Comment: The problem is that Swift does not really have a preprocessor, therefore "setting flags" is not something you should normally do. Personally I would just use a variable (either global or on a singleton) and the variable itself would be hidden behind `#if DEBUG`.

Comment: @Sulthan and now I'm catching on:
```
static let allLogs = true
#if DEBUG
if (allLogs) { print("Log message: \(message)") }
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift5 and XCode 14 can definitely use the compiler directives as you mention:

```
#if !DEBUG
#error("This is debug code, don't ship!!")
#endif
```